# Как правильно написать библиотеку на android studio для unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d

Пробую написать библиотеку на Android Studio для unity вот поэтому видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJE1hsYQYYw . Все работало если в build.grudle вот так вот написать:

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/classes.jar')
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
  //  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   // testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
   // androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Но беда мне понадобился там провайдер для сохранения файл для смартфона. Файл Манифеста:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.unitytestexam">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
       </application>

</manifest>
```

Пришлось рас комментировать `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'` Библиотека и приложение в unity все скомпилировалось. Но при запуске на смартфоне это приложение unity c моей библиотекой вылетает, почему?

Comment: Попробуйте мою библиотеку Android API For Unity, там есть множество функций: https://github.com/AntonRls/AndroidAPIForUnity

Comment: Неплохо, жаль функций там мало и не те что мне надо